# making filterWhen() with Mono predicate parallel

Tags: java, flux, reactor

With the Reactor Flux filterWhen, I see some behaviour that I need to overcome.

Given the following code:

```
Flux.fromIterable(List.of(1,2))
  .filterWhen(it -> predicateMono(it))
```

Where:

```
Mono<boolean> predicateMono(int value) { ... }
```

I noticed that the `predicateMono()`s are executed sequentially, meaning that for the value 2 the operation is not called until the first one has completed.

This becomes a problem when the `predicateMono()`s in my code are http calls to backend system that I would like to execute parallel. How do I write this so that I can filter the flux values in parallel fashion?

The `predicateMono()` are non blocking http calls, compatible with the reactive approach.

Comment: Read the tags before using them. The mono tag is not for Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution is to use `flatmap` instead of the `filterwhen`. Just map to empty in case you want to filter out. The empty values on Flux are just ignored for upcoming operations.

```
Flux.fromIterable(List.of(1, 2))
        .flatMap(it ->
            predicateMono(it).flatMap(result ->
                result ? Mono.just(it) : Mono.empty()));
```